# JDBC query table names case insensitive?

Tags: java, jdbc, schema, case-insensitive

**tl:dr;** Is there a way to select table names case insensitive over JDBC?

I try to extract all table names from a database over a JDBC connection. I can do this easily by

```
ResultSet tablesRst = connection.getMetaData().getTables( null, null, null, null );
```

This, however, returns ALL tables, views etc. I just need the first 10 that match a pattern. I know I can build this myself by manipulating the arguments.

The case of the pattern matters, I cannot find table `AAP` if the pattern is `a%`.

Is there an easy way to query table names over JDBC, without having to resort to database-specific code?

Answer (score 0):

That probably depends on the database configuration. If you turn off case sensitivity on your database, I'm assuming AAP will come back for a%.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I do not control the database, I only extract it..

Comment: Ah, then I guess it's either a vendor specific query using `where upper(x) = ?` or it's two hits to getTables() with 'a%' and 'A%'. The latter gets very difficult if it's more than one character.